# Looping through string, adding all numbers e.g. '123' = 1+2+3, demo with working loop included

Tags: sql-server-2005, string, integer, sum

This works to output the string `123456` as:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Code:

```
declare @string varchar(20)
declare @index int
declare @len int
declare @char char(1)

set @string = '123456'
set @index = 1
set @len= LEN(@string)

WHILE @index<= @len
BEGIN
set @char = SUBSTRING(@string, @index, 1)
print @char

SET @index= @index+ 1
END
```

But when I try to use this code to add those values up when looping through them (1+2+3+4+5+6 = 21), then I do no get a result from SQL, please help

```
declare @string varchar(20)
declare @index int
declare @len int
declare @char char(1)

set @string = '123456'
set @index = 1
set @len= LEN(@string)

declare @Total int 


WHILE @index<= @len
BEGIN
set @char = SUBSTRING(@string, @index, 1)
set @Total = @Total + cast(@char as int)

SET @index= @index+ 1
END

print @Total
```

Comment: declare @Total int = 0 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `@Total` to a default value, otherwise it is `NULL` and `NULL` + anything always returns `NULL`.

Changing this line returns `21` for me:

```
declare @Total int
```

to

```
declare @Total int = 0
```

That being said, this is not a great thing to try to do on a large number of rows.  If you need to do this on scalar values like you are using there, you may want to consider using a scalar udf for it.  This will NOT scale well though so if you use it against a table be prepared to wait a while.